# Problems updating single product price reactjs/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a product with my calculations in react/redux.

In my redux state for single product price is 400 and for single product quantity is 1,

So, I created a selection input from 1- 10 for updating the single product quantity state in my redux store. Now whenever user selects a number ranging from 1 to 10, the number will automatically update the single product quantity. Fine that works well!

Now the problem is, I can't update the product price after the quantity has been updated

For example, if a user selects 6 as quantity in the first run it works well but if the user decided to change the quantity from 6 to 2 or maybe 5, the product price will automatically update the product price by 6 ×2 ×5.

Is there anyway I can do it so whenever a user selects an option it gets multiply by the initial product price state instead of using the newly created state. Please !

STATES IN CART PRODUCTS COMPONENT

```
     const quantityNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
      const [qtyValue, setQtyValue] = useState();
      const [totalProductPrice, setTotalproductPrice] = useState(data.newPrice);
const selectQuantityNumber = quantityNumbers.map((num) => (
    <Option value={num}>{num}</Option>
  ));
```

SELECTION COMPONENT

```
         <Select
          labelInValue
          defaultValue={{ value: data.units }}
          style={{
            width: "50px",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            border: "0",
          }}
          onChange={selectUnitHandle}
          bordered={false}
        >
          {selectQuantityNumber}
        </Select>
```

SELECT FUNCTIONS

```
     const selectUnitHandle = (e) => {
            setQtyValue(e.value);
          };
//updateQty function is Set for dispatching redux action for choosing qty and updating single product price

    function updadeQty(item, qty, price) {
    qty = qtyValue;
    price = totalProductPrice;
    dispatch(chooseQty(data, qtyValue));
    setTotalproductPrice(data.newPrice * qtyValue);
    dispatch(UpdateSinglePrice(data, qty, price));
  }
```

MY REDUCER FOR UPDATING PRODUCT PRICE

```
case "UPDATE_SINGLE_PRICE": {
  let newItemPrice;
  let newItemQty;
  let updatedItem = state.cartItems.find(
    (prd) => action.item.id === prd.id
  );
  if (updatedItem) {
    newItemPrice = action.price;
    newItemQty = action.unit;
    updatedItem.newPrice = newItemPrice * newItemQty;
  } else return { ...state };
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet where you are doing this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mutating the default price you have in the store i.e do away with the part of code that changes the price value in the store, instead, calculate the price value of at the point of rendering as:

```
item.price * item.qty
```

All you need to update in the store is the item quantity, let them item price be as is. That should fix(and simplify) the total price claculation.

Comment: Thank you mate...doing this now

Comment: You're welcome. You should [accept or upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solves the problem.